# Stream video from Google Drive in VideoView on Android 5.1+

Tags: android, video, video-streaming, google-drive-android-api, android-5.1.1-lollipop

So lots of people have asked this question in one form or another, but no one seems to have an answer, and none of the proposed answers have worked for me, so I'm asking again.

The problem is that, as of Android 5.1, certain video urls won't play.  The only error in the log is

```
06-02 23:22:53.940 32469-32469/com.example.myapp W/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open https://<URL...>: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: https://<URL...>
06-02 23:22:54.081 32469-32499/com.example.myapp D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0x7d9cc48800 (GridView) with handle 0x7d9c084400
06-02 23:22:54.857 32469-32480/com.example.myapp I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 53228(4MB) AllocSpace objects, 1(20KB) LOS objects, 33% free, 9MB/13MB, paused 7.612ms total 44.857ms
06-02 23:22:55.487 32469-3238/com.example.myapp E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147483648)
06-02 23:22:55.500 32469-32469/com.example.myapp E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-2147483648)
06-02 23:22:55.500 32469-32469/com.example.myapp D/VideoView: Error: 1,-2147483648
06-02 23:22:55.503 32469-32469/com.example.myapp D/VideoPlayerActivity: MediaPlayer error: what = 1 extra = -2147483648
06-02 23:22:55.556 32469-32474/com.example.myapp I/art: Do partial code cache collection, code=62KB, data=52KB
06-02 23:22:55.556 32469-32474/com.example.myapp I/art: After code cache collection, code=62KB, data=52KB
06-02 23:22:55.556 32469-32474/com.example.myapp I/art: Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB
```

Now some people will tell you that the video you want to play just doesn't have a support codec on the device.  No way... first off, I am still able to play the same video on the same device using android 5.0.2, but not 5.1.1.  Second, if I take the video url and load it into a WebView on 5.1.1 and above, it will play.  So it's not the codec or the hardware.  I've tried every variety or URL encoding/decoding there is, and none of that has worked either.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
Uri videoUri = Uri.parse(vidAddress);
        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        videoView.setVideoURI(videoUri, headers);
        videoView.seekTo(resumePoint);
        videoView.setMediaController(null);
        videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(final MediaPlayer mp) {
                View loadingIndicator = findViewById(R.id.loading_indicator);
                loadingIndicator.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                videoProgress.setMax(videoView.getDuration());
                videoProgress.setSecondaryProgress(videoView.getDuration());
                endTime.setText(getTimeString(videoView.getDuration()));
            }
        });

        videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(final MediaPlayer mp) {
                finish();
            }
        });

videoView.start();
```

UPDATE: Since it's true that some URLs do work with the above code, I'm adding some more info.  The URLs I'm using are of MP4 videos stored in Google Drive.  The `videoUri` variable is populated using the `downloadUrl` field from the Google Drive File response, and the `headers` contains the authorization header with the token for the logged in account.  Like I said, ALL of this code, unaltered from above, works without issue on API 5.0.2 and below, and not on 5.1.1.  Tests were performed with two devices of the same hardware (Two Nexus 5x's, and Two Nexus Players), changing nothing else but the OS version.  The code above works on both the 5x and the player running 5.0.2, but not on either running 5.1.1.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52892844/i-am-trying-to-play-video-from-google-drive-using-shareable-link-in-video-view-b) seems best on 2019: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52892844/i-am-trying-to-play-video-from-google-drive-using-shareable-link-in-video-view-b

Answer (score 0):

Under the covers, when you call `setVideoUri()`, it is calling [MediaPlayer.setDataSource(Context, Uri)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setDataSource(android.content.Context,%20android.net.Uri)), which only supports content URIs (i.e., not http/https URLs).

Instead, it is suggested to use [ExoPlayer](https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/) which is much more full featured and fully supports streaming from web URLs. If you'd like to maintain a VideoView type interface, you can use a wrapper library such as [ExoMedia](https://github.com/brianwernick/ExoMedia)

Comment: Looking at the API 21 source, if the scheme isn't "file", `setDataSource(Context, Uri)`eventually calls through to `nativeSetDataSource(MediaHTTPService.createHttpServiceBinderIfNecessary(path),path,keys,values);` So it seems like that should be fine for urls.  And certain urls DO work, just the one I'm using for some reason only works for Android 5.0.2 and below.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using 
`videoView.start()` 
after 
`videoView.setVideoURI()`. I've tried this using a HTTP URL address, and it works.
Or maybe something wrong with the HTTPs protocol?

Answer (score 0):

Use MediaController for play video from Url

```
VideoView videoview;
MediaController mediacontroller;
try {
            mediacontroller = new MediaController(VideoPlayActivity.this);
            mediacontroller.setAnchorView(videoview);
            Uri video = Uri.parse(VideoURL);
            videoview.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
            videoview.setVideoURI(video);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: I'm specifically setting the media controller to null so that I can use a custom video control that I wrote. Regardless, the media controller shouldn't affect the ability to playback at all, it just adds video controls (play/pause, seek) to interact with the stream once it's playing.