# I am trying to play video from google drive using shareable link in video view but unable to play what is the solution for this?

Tags: android, google-drive-api

this is my code

```
mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoview);

VideoView videoView = findViewById(R.id.videoview);
// videoPath="https://drive.google.com/open?id=1dXndP-MjQL7USlP0EtaElx67mXujqCSX";
//
Uri uri = Uri.parse(videoPath);
videoView.setVideoURI(uri);

MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to edit the link. Use **String** functions to edit the text.

- Replace `open?` with `uc?authuser=0&`.
- Add `&export=download` at URL text ending.

so `videoPath=` like below:

```
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1dXndP-MjQL7USlP0EtaElx67mXujqCSX
```

becomes:

```
https://drive.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=1dXndP-MjQL7USlP0EtaElx67mXujqCSX&export=download
```

Example code:

```
//# fix path
videoPath = videoPath.replace("open?", "uc?authuser=0&");
videoPath = videoPath + "&export=download";

//# try to play
Uri uri = Uri.parse(videoPath);
videoView.setVideoURI(uri);

MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
```